# How to properly escape characters in regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I want to do a string search inside a string. Simply saying `MySTR.search(Needle)`.

The problem occurs when this `needle` string contains special regex characters like *,+ and so on. It fails with error `invalid quantifier`.

I have browsed the web and found out that string can be escaped with `\Q some string \E`.

However, this does not always produce the desired behavior. For example:

```
var sNeedle = '*Stars!*';
var sMySTR = 'The contents of this string have no importance';
sMySTR.search('\Q' + sNeedle + '\E');
```

Result is -1. OK.

```
var sNeedle = '**Stars!**';
var sMySTR = 'The contents of this string have no importance';
sMySTR.search('\Q' + sNeedle + '\E');
```

Result is "invalid quantifier". This happens because 2 or more special characters are 'touching' each other, because:

```
var sNeedle = '*Dont touch me*Stars!*Dont touch me*';
var sMySTR = 'The contents of this string have no importance';
sMySTR.search('\Q' + sNeedle + '\E');
```

Will work OK.

I know I could make a function `escapeAllBadChars(sInStr)` and just add double slashes before every possible special regex character, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do it?

Comment: \Q...\E works in Perl, not sure about anywhere else though.

Comment: I think the stars in your third example aren't doing what you think. They're not being interpreted as literal * characters, but as quantifiers for the characters before them.

Comment: @Matthew, in Java it works the same as in Perl (not sure about other languages).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`\Q...\E` doesn't work in JavaScript (at least, they don't escape anything...) as you can see:

```
var s = "*";
print(s.search(/\Q*\E/));
print(s.search(/\*/));
```

produces:

```
-1
0
```

as you can see on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/4sFZ1).

The following chars need to be escaped:

- `(`
- `)`
- `[`
- `{`
- `*`
- `+`
- `.`
- `$`
- `^`
- `\`
- `|`
- `?`

So, something like this would do:

```
function quote(regex) {
  return regex.replace(/([()[{*+.$^\\|?])/g, '\\$1');
}
```

No, `]` and `}` don't need to be escaped: they have no special meaning, only their opening counter parts.

Note that when using a literal regex, `/.../`, you also need to escape the `/` char. However, `/` is not a regex meta character: when using it in a `RegExp` object, it doesn't need an escape.

Comment: character / needs to be escaped as well

Comment: @TheoZ, I wouldn't call `/` de regex meta char. It only needs an escape when you use a literal regex. When creating the regex with a `RegExp` object, it doesn't need an escape. But since I give an example with `/.../`, it's a good idea to mention it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just dipping my feet in Javascript, but is there a reason you need to use the regex engine at all?  How about

```
var sNeedle = '*Stars!*';
var sMySTR = 'The contents of this string have no importance';
if ( sMySTR.indexOf(sNeedle) > -1 ) {
   //found it
}
```

Comment: I haven't really thought about this. It is just stuck in my head that i should use .search() .match() .replace() with strings. In fact, all i want to do is use sNeedle as simple text string, so i think the indexOf is sure a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I performed a quick Google search to see what's out there and it appears that you've got a few options for escaping regular expression characters. According to [one page](http://simonwillison.net/2006/Jan/20/escape/), you can define & run a function like below to escape problematic characters:

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Alternatively, you can try and use a separate library such as [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/), which already handles nuances you're trying to re-solve.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/151312

This is proper as per MDN (see explanation in post above):

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```