# RegExp: is there way to pass string to regexp without ecranisation?

Tags: regex, pcre

Is there way to pass some string to regexp and not worry about ecranisation of special chars.

For example I wont to find line which starts with words "\north+west\", as you can see "\n" and "h+" should be ecranised. So question is there some special combination to write text as it is?

```
/^\s+(<some special combination> \north+west\)\s+/i
```

or maybe you know function which can properly ecranise my text?

Comment: Most languages provide some function to escape strings that should be inserted into a regular expression. Which language do you use?

Comment: Please note that the description for the `regex` tag states: *Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.*

Comment: If this is JS, this is already asked several times on SO.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig right now I need it in PHP but I thought there can be standard way for all PCRE languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP and Perl you can use `\Q...\E` delimiters to autoescape metacharacters inside regexp. Quoting [**the doc**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> `\Q` and `\E` can be used to ignore regexp metacharacters in the pattern.
>   For example: `\w+\Q.$.\E$` will match one or more word characters,
>   followed by literals `.$.` and anchored at the end of the string.

Comment: just found [\Q...\E doesn't work in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5664273/815295) "Hulk sad" :(

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work in JS; that's why you were asked to provide a language tag as well, btw. ) But there's a plenty of 'autoescaping' code out there; in fact, jQuery UI (and other popular tools) have the corresponding methods in their libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@raina77ow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972106/regexp-is-there-way-to-pass-string-to-regexp-without-ecranisation#15974985), when you use pcre via a language like PHP that needs pattern delimiters, you can't use the `\Q...\E` feature if your string contains the opening or the closing delimiter. For example, you can't write patterns like:

```
/\Qabc/def\E/
~\Qabc~def\E~
[\Qabc[def\E]
[\Qabc]def\E]
(\Qabc)def\E)
(\Qabc(def\E)
```

The only way is to use the [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) function and to put the delimiter *(only if this one isn't already a special regex character)* in its second parameter.