# Search in page with JavaScript Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

i would build a page with Bootstrap and i would use the navbar-search form for find the searched text in the same page.
What JS script i should use for do this? 
I would that for every found text in the page the script add class "lead" to the p tag like this

```
    <p class="lead">...</p>
```

How i can do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? You want the user to type in the navbar-search form, and you want the JS script to add the "lead" class to every `<p>` element that contains a match for the search string?

Comment: yes, for every found element on this page i would add the class lead to the <p> tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Bootstrap requires jQuery for its plugins to work, I'll use it for your solution:

If your `navbar-search` is a class:

```
$(".navbar-search").on("keyup", function () {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $(".lead").removeClass("lead");
    $("p").each(function () {
        if (v != "" && $(this).text().search(v) != -1) {
            $(this).addClass("lead");
        }
    });
});
```

Bear in mind that this will not look for words but for characters (so when you start typing say `a`, it will select both paragraphs straight away since both of them contain 'a'). If you want to search for words, you need to amend your code accordingly.

This solution is case-sensitive.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zx2nz/)

So if you want to search for whole words, do this:

```
$(".navbar-search").on("keyup", function () {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $(".lead").removeClass("lead");
    var re = new RegExp("\\b" + v + "\\b","g")
    $("p").each(function () {
        if (v != "" && $(this).text().search(re) != -1) {
            $(this).addClass("lead");
        }
    });
});
```

Just bear in mind that you might want to escape your `v` before inserting it into the regexp if you expect people to search for something silly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zx2nz/1/)

Comment: +1, good solution. However you don't have to expect people to search for something "silly" in order to need to escape your regexp substring. If anyone searches for "U.S." or "[1" or "$4" or possibly "(a", they could get errors or wrong results. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5664273/423105 on how to escape the string.

Comment: @LarsH: Thanks, I agree that the string should be escaped regardless, but I didn't want to complicate the example.