# Javascript regex handle /

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace this string literally: `/:)`

However, if I do it like this

```
test = text.replace(//:\)/gi, replacement);
```

Javascript will treat `//` as the beginning of a comment. If I do it like this (add brackets):

```
test = text.replace(/(/:\))/gi, replacement);
```

this is a syntax error, since it will treat `/(/` as the pattern

What can I do get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about escaping the forward slash with a back slash also:

```
test = text.replace(/\/:\)/gi, replacement);
```

Comment: Oh right, silly me. I was looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663987/how-to-properly-escape-characters-in-regexp and thought that `/` doesn't need to be escaped. Thanks!