# Javascript pattern for test from input value

Tags: javascript, regex, input, html-lists

What I want is simple. I have an input field and I want to check what items from an unordered list (`ul`) contain the input's value.

So, I have this:

```
$('input#search').keyup(
    function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value.length > 0) {
            var patt = /value/g;
            console.log(patt);
            $('ul#list li').filter(function() {
                return (patt.test($(this).html()));
            });
        }
     }
);
```

My problem here is that if, for example, the value of the input is *'abcd'* patt will be `/value/g` instead of `/abcd/g` so I want to know how can I insert the value in the pattern.

Comment: var patt = new RegExp(pattern);

Comment: wouldn't [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) be a better fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a pattern based on dynamic data you'd use the [`RegExp` ctor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) passing it a string of the pattern. e.g.

```
var word = 'foo';
var re = new RegExp(word, 'g'); // var re = /foo/g
```

*Don't forget to [escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663987/how-to-properly-escape-characters-in-regexp) with special meaning in regexp.*

However, if you're just looking for a simple "is x within y" comparison, [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) can perform this check very quickly:

```
var sample = 'this is a foo sentence';
var loc = 'Hello, world!'.indexOf('world') // 7
```

then simply check if `indexOf(...) != -1`.

Answer (score 0):

define patt as new RegExp

```
var patt = new RegExp(value,"g")
```